# How to share custom Grails Plugins with in-house svn repository?

Tags: svn, grails, plugins

we want to share a custom in-house plugin with our developers using svn.
I was wondering if this is possible and how we could achieve this.

We do not want to share only the binary but also the code from the plugins.

The perfect solution would be that we could indicate in our BuildConfig that an external plugin is required using svn.

/Marco

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to share internal plugins by using a Maven repository, which is now the preferred way. See section "Publishing to Maven Compatible Repositories" at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#repositories.
[Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php) are two good options.
You can publish your plugin by using the [release](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-release/docs/index.html) plugin.
Then add your maven repo and plugin to BuildConfig.groovy:

```
repositories {
   ...
   mavenRepo "http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
}
...
plugins {
   ...
   compile ":my-plugin:1.1"
}
```

By default plugins are published as source, unless you use the --binary option.